# Drupal 7 - field template - $item - img tag

Tags: theming

In drupal 7 theme, I have the following file:

field--field_photo.tpl.php
     clearfix">
    
    >: 
    
    >
     $item) : ?>
    ">

Inside render($item) lies an image with img tag
How I may deconstruct this item, so that I write my code with img tag?
The reason is just that I want to add a class to this img tag. thanks

The path to the images are save in public:files format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module to figure out things like this. Install and enable Devel, then add something like this to your field template file:

```
<?php kpr($item); ?>
```

This will show you all the contents of $item (arrays and objects). Then you can just print the part that you want (the img tag in this case), wrapped in the extra class.

Comment: thanks. is this output invisible to anonymous users? I was already use devel. How come kpr shows some extra output like "children" which shows the full html output (img tag with full link) whereas the normal krumo display does not?

Comment: a part of the question remains. how to convert the public:uri that is saved in the database to a full url.